# WIFI adaptor is not found in ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS in asus vivobook 15 amd ryzen 7

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, dual-boot, asus

I'm using asus vivobook of model M515D. i had ubuntu 22.04 earlier dual booted with windows 11 but the ubuntu got corrupted so i decided to delete and reinstall ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Alongside with windows 11. After booting i found a error that wifi adaptor is not found. Can anyone help me with this please. I'm not a computer geek so give your solutions in brief. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxrzc0` in terminal